Download popup window is still appearing in Selenium
While running the selenium script in grid. The download popup window is getting appeared. The same script is getting run in local computer.
These are the pref for the chromedriver
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("directory_upgrade", true);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", Config.getBrowserDownloadLocation());

I have checked the download settings in the grid laptop the Ask where to save each file before downloading was off in the that machine too. Still getting that download popup

this can happen when path is not valid or the browser doesn't have proper permissions to write to the directory.  Try running a quick check in your code for the existence of the directory before setting the pref.  (you could possibly create that directory and/or set permissions if it doesn't exist)  btw, the only thing you should need to set is prefs.put("download.default_directory"....)
